# Change column from NOT LOGGED to LOGGED

Tags: db2, ddl, db2-luw, db2-10.5, hadr

I have a database DAT1 running on DB2 version 10.5. 
I want to enable logging for all CLOB and BLOB columns of my table TAB1.
The table was initially created with those columns as `NOT LOGGED` but now I need to change it to `LOGGED`.

I know there is the procedure [ALTOBJ](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0011934.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0&lang=en)

that should be able to change this attribute. However I learned form the documentation that this procedure do the following:

> The procedure backs up the data of the table being altered, then drops the original table and creates a new version using the DDL statement; the final step loads the stored data back into the new table.

I need to modify many tables and the size of each table normally reaches about 10GB or even more. This means that this operation may require a very large amount of free disk space plus the time needed to create the new table and copy back the data.

I'm wondering if this operation can be achieved also with a simple `ALTER TABLE` or another command which doesn't involve creating or copying new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot alter the `LOGGED` attribute of a LOB column. However, you can alter the table by adding a new `LOGGED` LOB column, update the new column from the existing column, then drop the original column. It may require less wasted disk space but is unlikely to be faster than using `ALTOBJ`.

Comment: Do I need to manually recreate all indexes, constraints etc ... after calling ALTOBJ ?

Comment: I believe `ALTOBJ` will re-create all dependent objects, but it's always a good idea to test first.

Comment: The drawback is that you have to parse the DDL generated and extract the CREATE TABLE statement which is not easy from SQL. So maybe creating a new LOGGED column is better but you may hit the row length limit which is 32K for DB2 LUW

Comment: LOB columns are not subject to the row length (page size) limit, because they are stored separately -- unless inlined, of course.

Comment: Yes the problem is that you have to specify an inline length >= 312 and once the column is created you can't decrease the value. You are allowed to only increase the value.